# Getting ERROR Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

This is the error i get when i do mvn test on github project.

PROJECT: apache_dubbo

REPO: https://github.com/apache/dubbo

HASH: 5d9638dd5ec6357d9d1fd55f5bb085eacb063d2d

[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\pontr\Desktop\apache-dubbo\dubbo-common\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Please help me
Thank you in advance

[error i get on mvn test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO5mm.png)

The strange thing is that when my friend to the maven test it works. He has the same jdk and maven version of me.

Comment: Instead of linking an image (which is not readable) it would be helpful to have the full text or even better would be a link to logoutput but I assume that one of your tests fails...

Comment: Try to zoom the image linked in the description

Answer (score 0):

In the image you are linking, you have failing tests.

One of the failing test is here: https://github.com/apache/dubbo/blob/4af8606b1d659d9b386a044ad886ddeba3299567/dubbo-common/src/test/java/org/apache/dubbo/common/io/UnsafeByteArrayOutputStreamTest.java

`testToStringWithCharset`

Comment: and so what can i do in order to make the test success?